# How to get the number of parameters that procedure accepts?

Tags: tcl

Is there a way in TCL to get the number of parameters that procedure accepts?
For example we have procedure:

```
proc func {a} {
    puts $a
}
```

I need a way to put in variable the number of parameters that `func` procedure accepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe try something like:

```
info args func
```

This will get the arguments that `func` require.

Then you can use it to get the number of arguments:

```
set num [llength [info args func]]
```

In your case, `$num` will be 1.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you for help. I used this solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931865/tcl-procedure-call-with-optional-parameters/22933612

Comment: This only gets the list of formal arguments. Beware of a magical final `args` formal…

Comment: and possible default arguments.